# Is there a way to specify beginning of line in a Pluma Search?

Tags: 20.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, search, pluma

Here is my description of the current system:

- Pluma 1.24.0
- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- MATE 1.24.0

I was trying to replace spaces with tabs, but only at the beginning of a line.
I could find spaces, and could find tabs, and even combinations of spaces and tabs.
I did have 'Match regular expression' and 'Parse escape sequences' checked.
I tried using a caret preceding the space, but it did not work.
I tried with other characters as well, but still no go.

Answer (score 2):

It works with leading tab `^\t`, but not with leading space `^` .

So it seems to be a bug in Pluma or its 3rd-party regexp-parsing library.

I have reported it [here](https://github.com/mate-desktop/pluma/issues/633).

As alternative you can use [Kate editor](https://kate-editor.org/) which can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install kate
```

Comment: As I said, "I tried using a caret preceding the space'

Comment: I still can't get ^\t to work.  
Nothing gets highlighted.  

I did find a workaround, though. I can precede the search term with a \n